# issue with inlinecallbacks twisted

Tags: python-2.7, twisted, deferred

i am writing twisted code .. first one with deferred second one with inlineCallbacks. first one works but second doesn't .. any idea or pointers

```
class Echo(LineReceiver):

    def lineReceived_callbacks(self, line):
        print self.sendLine("i received :%s"%line)
                    def pp(res):
            print "from callback",res
            self.sendLine(str(res))

        d = self.factory.dbs.getResult(line)
        d.addCallback(pp)

    @defer.inlineCallbacks
    def lineReceived(self, line):
       res = yield self.factory.dbs.getResult(line)
       print res
       self.sendLine(str(res))
```

`self.factory.dbs.getResult(line)` returns a deferred.

Answer (score -1):

got solution..

seems like a issue in twisted.
http://twistedmatrix.com/pipermail/twisted-python/2006-October/014277.html

if lineReceived returns a deferred connection drops in defer example deferred is created but not returned and in second because using inlineCallbacks, it returns deferred always and hence connection drop .. lineReceived is basic stuff and should be workable with inlineCallbacks..